# Подскажите, какая ошибка присутствует в моем коде? С++

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели

Я написал код для вычисления произведения двух двумерных неквадратных матриц. Размер матрицы задается пользователем, значения элементов матриц выбираются рандомно. Если матрицы не равны по размерности, то произведение не высчитывается.

В результате, после произведения двух матриц arr и arr2, все элементы матрицы result равны между собой. Не могу понять, почему так выходит

Код C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

void Array(int** arr, int** arr2, int** result, int n, int m, int n1, int m1)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        *(arr  + i) = new int[m];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
    {
        *(arr2 + i) = new int[m1];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        *(result + i) = new int[m1];
    }
}

void fillArray(int** arr, int** arr2, int n, int m, int n1, int m1)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = rand() % 50 - 25;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m1; j++)
        {
            arr2[i][j] = rand() % 50 - 25;
        }
    }

}

void showArray(int** arr, int** arr2, int n, int m, int n1, int m1)
{
    cout << "Первый массив: " << endl;
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Второй массив: " << endl;
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m1; j++)
        {
            cout << arr2[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

bool Check(int** arr, int** arr2, int n, int m, int n1, int m1)
{
    if (n != n1 || m != m1)
    {
        cout << "Произведение матриц не может быть вычислено, так как кол-во строк и столбцов массивов не совпадают" << endl;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

void function(int** arr, int** arr2, int** result, int n, int m, int n1, int m1)
{
    for (int r1 = 0; r1 < n; r1++) 
    {
        for (int r2 = 0; r2 < m1; r2++) 
        {
            result[r1][r2] = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                {
                    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < n1; i1++)
                    {
                        for (int j1 = 0; j1 < m1; j1++)
                        {
                            result[r1][r2] = arr[i][j] * arr2[i1][j1];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void Result(int** result, int n, int m1)
{
    cout << "Результат уменожения массивов: " << endl;
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m1; j++)
        {
            cout << result[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    srand(time(0));
    int n = 0;
    int m = 0;
    int n1 = 0;
    int m1 = 0;

    cout << "Введите кол-во строк первого массива " << endl;
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Введите кол-во столбцов первого массива " << endl;
    cin >> m;

    cout << "Введите кол-во строк второго массива " << endl;
    cin >> n1;
    cout << "Введите кол-во столбцов второго массива " << endl;
    cin >> m1;

    int** arr = new int*[n];
    int** arr2 = new int* [n1];
    int** result = new int* [n];

    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;

    Array(arr, arr2, result, n, m, n1, m1);
    fillArray(arr, arr2, n, m, n1, m1);
    showArray(arr, arr2, n, m, n1, m1);
    if (Check(arr, arr2, n, m, n1, m1))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    function(arr, arr2, result, n, m, n1, m1);
    Result(result, n, m1);
    
}
```

[image: Вот, что получается в результате:]

Comment: Да у вас даже проверка возможности умножения - и та неверная... И скажите - если уж у вас С++, то почему вы работаете методами С?

Comment: умножение матриц реализовано, мягко говоря, не верно... хинт: там должно быть всего 3 вложенных цикла...

Comment: Я только начинаю изучать C++ в университете, мой преподаватель показывал примеры решений подобных задач, ну и я, опираясь на эти примеры, написал код

Comment: Что вы уже знаете? Классы? хотя бы структуры в духе С?

Comment: Циклы, условные операторы, функции, классы немного затронули , массивы, указатели и некоторые другие операторы, на счет структуры в духе С немного не понял, изучали год назад С крайне поверхностно и немного

Answer (score 1):

Потому что значения элементов матрицы-результата вычисляются одинаково и совершенно не зависят от того, где эти элементы находятся.

```
result[r1][r2] = arr[i][j] * arr2[i1][j1];
```